# Using Jquery.attr() to Get DIV IDs

Tags: php, jquery, html, each, attr

I want to use the .each and .attr function to get div ids.  I know how to do that, but what I want to do is grab each div ID from the DOM with a certain class (let's say "edit" class) and .append some data into that div.

Here's what I am having trouble with:  I want to put the ID of that particular DIV in the .each loop inside the .append.  For example: if I wanted to put a link inside the .append, I would want the link to be http://www.website.com/index.php?id=1&div=DIV-ID

Any ideas, and I'm sorta a novice, so can you provide code example.  I understand attr and .each though to an extent.

Comment: *"I want to put the ID of that particular DIV in the .each loop inside the .append."* - Wait... what?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense as-is. Could you explain the input you expect and walk us, step-by-step, through what you want to happen? I suspect that what you want is do-able, but currently it's difficult to guess what you want.

Comment: His question makes perfect sense. He wants the <div id> attribute to wind up inside the same div as part of a link. He even posted some of the methods he's tried (i.e. .each and .attr), so he's clearly researched something. He just needs help putting it together.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, I have done my research on .each and .append, and I've gotten them to display all the divs, but not just a particular div.  I believe the answers below have helped.

Comment: @Morgan The sentence I quoted in my comment above is far from making sense. It is not clear what is being asked.

Comment: @Vidas: For every .each, .append some data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WrGLC/1/

For the sake of keeping it on this page:

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="edit">A</div>
<div id="2" class="edit">B</div>
<div id="3">C</div>
```

JS:

```
// Anonymous loop, in case you copy and paste this script, the vars won't get confused
(function() {

    // Loop for each .edit
    $('.edit').each(function() {

        // Update the text inside
        $(this).html('http://www.website.com/id='+$(this).attr('id'));

    });

})();
```

Comment: thanks Morgan, this looks like what I was looking for.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: NP. Change the html() parameter. It can either be an existing object, or if you're creating it on the fly, you can do something like $(this).html('<img src="your-image.jpg" alt="The id is '+this.id+'" />');

Comment: thanks for the insight.  I was actually wanting to put the href with the div id around my image, but I figured it out through some quick testing.  Thanks though, I might need to know that info too!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested solution that looks like it should work.  It may not work if there are multiple classes assigned to the `div` elements.

```
$(function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
        var _t = $(this);
        var id = _t.attr("id");
        if(_t.attr("class") == "someClass") {
            _t.append("<a href = 'http://www.website.com/index.php?id=1&div="+id+"'>Hello World!</a>");

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess. You want this?

```
$( '.edit' ).append( function () {
    return '<a href="http://www.website.com/index.php?id=1&div=' + 
        this.id + '">link</a>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe an jQuery call to each() would be necessary. With [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) you can pass a function where this will represent the current iteration of your selector.

```
$('div.mydivclass').append(function () {
  return '<a href="http://www.website.com/index.php?id=1&div='+ this.id + '">My Div link</a>';
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WFd7k/

Answer (score 0):

I **think** I'm correctly interpreting your conditions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a" class="edit">A</div>
        <div id="b" class="edit">B</div>
        <div id="c">C</div>
        <div id="d" class="save">D</div>
        <div id="e" class="edit">E</div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                $("div.edit").each(function (i) {
                    var $div = $(this);
                    $div.append('<a href="http://www.website.com/index.php?id=1&div=' + $div.attr("id") + '">Link</a>');
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:** @JohnHartsock is correct. No each method is needed here. I'd adjust my code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a" class="edit">A</div>
        <div id="b" class="edit">B</div>
        <div id="c">C</div>
        <div id="d" class="save">D</div>
        <div id="e" class="edit">E</div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                $("div.edit").append(function () {
                    var $div = $(this);
                    $div.append('<a href="http://www.website.com/index.php?id=1&div=' + $div.attr("id") + '">Link</a>');
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you mean to put (i) after funtion, or did you mean (id)?